# How to unpack into a folder containing a point in the name

Tags: 7zip

I'm using 7zip command line tool and I have an instruction like this

```
7z x -oDebug/Folder.with.point bin.7z
```

However, when I run this, it searches for a file with the extension *.with.point*. How do I tell the program I mean a folder. I tried surrounding the name with quotation marks and escaping the points with backslashes, but both of these things didn't work.

And why **can** the program even interpret the argument of the -o switch as a file? Shouldn't it be implied by the option that whatever follows is a directory? I'm pretty sure extractong into a file isn't something you can do (or that makes sense).

Comment: Which version of 7z do you use?

Comment: Whatever version [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/7zip) uses. It seems like the command line tool has no version switch so I can't actually tell you. I'm also dependend on using the npm version as I'm using it in a Windows Docker container.